# Tables in memory and tables normal on procedure stored using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-memory-database

I am trying to rewrite a stored procedure to a natively compiled stored procedure. The procedure refers to 4 tables; these tables are normal tables (non memory-optimized) and I am using 2 views related to it.

Is it possible to create a natively compiled stored procedure without converting any of these objects to memory-optimized tables?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Ok, I'll do my best

Comment: I am trying to rewrite a stored procedure to Natively compiled stored procedure. The procedure refers to 4 tables, these tables are normal tables (non memory optimised) and I am using 2 views related to it. Is it possible to create a Natively Compiled stored procedure without converting any of these objects to Memory optimised tables?

Comment: @Lucas, when adding details that affect the question, please edit the question rather than leaving a comment. Comments can be ephemeral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, natively compiled stored procedures cannot reference disk-based tables, only memory-optimized ones. Here is a quote from Kalen Delaney's book [SQL Server Internals: In-Memory OLTP](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/entrypage/sql-server-internals):

> However, there are limitations on the T-SQL language constructs that are allowed inside a natively compiled stored procedure, compared to the rich feature set available with interpreted code. **In addition, natively compiled stored procedures can only access memory-optimized tables and cannot reference disk-based tables.**

I could not find clear statement in the official Microsoft Docs for that, except [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transact-sql-constructs-not-supported-by-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-2017#memory-optimized-tables) limitation, which is direct consequence of the fact, that natively compiled stored procedures can't reference "normal" tables:

> For memory-optimized tables, FOREIGN KEY constraints are only supported for foreign keys referencing primary keys of **other memory-optimized tables**.

Comment: Well, the `FROM` clause limits specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/supported-features-for-natively-compiled-t-sql-modules?view=sql-server-2017#qsancsp) is also a pretty big clue.

Comment: Yep, absolutely! :) Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thanks for the reply :)